# If $1+1\ne 0$ in a commutative ring $A$, then the quaternion algebra over $A$ is not commutative.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, quaternions

> Let $A$ be a commutative ring, $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in A$ and $E$ the
> quaternion algebra over $A$ whose underlying module is $A^{\oplus 4}$
> and whose multiplication table is given by  \begin{align} i^2&=\alpha
>  e+\beta i, & ij&=k, & ik&=\alpha j+\beta k,\\ ji&=\beta j-k, &
>  j^2&=\gamma e, & jk&=\beta\gamma e-\gamma i,\\ ki&=-\alpha j, &
>  kj&=\gamma i, & k^2&=-\alpha\gamma i, \end{align} where $(e,i,j,k)$ is the canonical basis of $A^{\oplus 4}$. Suppose $1+1\ne0$ in
> $A$. Then $E$ is not commutative.

Let $N_E$ denote the Cayley norm of $E$. Then
$$N_E(\rho e+\xi i+\eta j+\zeta k)=(\rho^2+\beta\rho\xi-\alpha\xi^2-\gamma(\eta^2+\beta\eta\zeta-\alpha\zeta^2))e,$$
for all $\rho,\xi,\eta,\zeta\in A$. It can be shown that $N_E(uv)=N_E(u)N_E(v)$ for all $u,v\in E$. The author claims that this latter equality together with $1+1\ne0$ imply that $E$ is not commutative. I cannot see this. Any suggestions how one might prove this?

Comment: Can't you just look at $ij-ji=2k-\beta j$? If $2\neq 0$, then this is nonzero, and you have an example of two elements which do not commute.

Comment: @KReiser yes that is the obvious way to show noncommutativity. I was just wondering about the connection to the norm.